# Script to powershell selected sharepoint objects (lists...)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

Is there any tool to script existing sharepoint objects for example lists, columns etc to powershell script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use native ISE or better [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) in collaboration with [PowerTab](http://powertab.codeplex.com/), they are free tools.

PrimalScript 2011 is a commercial editor that provide code completion for both SharePoint and Exchange, syntax coloring, and dynamic help for modules and snapins. The 2011 products also support 64Bit snapins and Modules.

Comment: PowerTab is the best module for speed-up works on PoSH console! Good sugeestion JP

Comment: But I would like tool to automaticaly generate scripts selecting for example list or other scriptable object. Is it possible to script all site to powershell without data, only sites, lists etc?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know such a tool, but it can be built.

Comment: I think about integration process where changes to my sharepoint application are deployed with powershell scripts. Every new script (change) is run and result is saved to sql table.